# what does mean #ifndef #define directive

Tags: c++, c, g++, directive

I am new in c++. When I create a header file Arme.h, I get automatically these instructions

```
#ifndef DEF_ARME
#define DEF_ARME
```

What does these mean and is it important?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: Don't forget the `#endif` at the end of the file!

Comment: Your editor is being annoyingly helpful xD

Answer (score 10):

```
#ifndef
```

means: "if not defined"

```
#define DEF_ARME
```

speaks for itself: here the "empty macro" "DEF_ARME" is defined. We can see this construction very often in header files: your whole header file will be included in these:

```
#ifndef HEADER_NAME
#define HEADER_NAME

(here the code you want to include only once, as is general the case for headers)

#endif
```

This way: the first time you include the header file, the macro "HEADER_NAME" isn't defined yet, so it will be defined and the header code will be included. If you include the same header later on, HEADER_NAME will be defined already, so the same code won't be included another time.

NOTE: The preprocessor directive

```
#ifndef
```

is a condition and (just like any "if then" construction) needs to be ended, in this case with

```
#endif
```

Comment: Notice that your example name is **invalid**, because an identifier starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter is reserved for the implementation, and its usage in client code is illegal.

Comment: ok I adapted this. thanks

Answer (score 3):

`#ifndef` = if not defined

`#define` = define

Recall also that:

`#include` = act as though the contents of the named file had been copied and pasted here

So the net effect is that with code like:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "A.h"
```

The first one does a `#define` and the second then declines to insert a second copy of the same text by virtue of the `#ifndef`.

Usually what would otherwise actually happen is more like:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

/* but B.h says:

   #include "A.h"

*/
```

So what you're avoiding is potential double declaration errors from the compiler anywhere that include dependencies are even slightly complicated.

Comment: Don't forget about the essential `#endif`

Answer (score 0):

All the header guards do is to only allow your headers to be included once. If they're included multiple times, they're simply ignored.
So defining it at the top of the header file will make sure its only included once in the program.

Answer (score 0):

It's a construction commonly used in header files. To prevent from #including multiple header files, you put #ifndef and #define 'something' that is specific for this header file. Next time you try to include the same header, your 'something' will be already defined and prevent from including.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can setup you source code on compile time by these macros like:

1.use specified function version

```
int factorial1(int n) 
 { 
 if (n<=1) return 1;
 return n*factorial1(n-1);
 }

int factorial2(int n) 
 {
 int f,i;
 for (f=1,i=2;i<=n;i++) f*=i;
 return f;
 }

#define factorial(n) factorial1(n)
//#define factorial(n) factorial2(n)

void main()
 {
 int i=factorial(10);
 }
```

2.avoid multiple include (good if you have global variables)

```
// this will avoid text below if _pi_h is already defined ... ie pi.h is already included
#ifndef _pi_h
// this will define global token _pi_h which means that file pi.h is already included
#define _pi_h

// global viariable
double pi=3.1415926535897932384626433832795;

// end of ifndef
#endif

// now you can do this without error (very handy for nested includes...)
#include "pi.h"
#include "pi.h"
#include "pi.h"
```

[notes]

- with macros can be done many things like turning on/off parts of code if some token is defined
- for example you have game and want some debug drawings while debuging but not in final app
- then just use define ... like in the pi.h example